# Working with Images in C#. Resize a Gif and save it as JPEG

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-manipulation, gdi

Hi I use C# ans Asp.Net4.

I create a class which re size a source image.
Code work great with JPEG File but if I upload a GIF I receive this error:

```
A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.
```

Here my code.. Any Ideas?

Exception line: `SD.Graphics newImage = SD.Graphics.FromImage(temp);`

```
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void ResizeImageWithAspect(string fileName, string outputFileName, int newWidth, int newResolution, string newCodec, int qualityLevel)
    {
        // Original Image
        SD.Image original = SD.Image.FromFile(fileName);

        // Find image aspect ratio computed by image height and width.
        float aspect = (float)original.Height / (float)original.Width;

        // Calculate the new height using the aspect ratio and the desired new width.
        int newHeight = (int)(newWidth * aspect);

        // Create a bitmap of the correct size. Bitmap it is used for image manipolation.
        SD.Bitmap temp = new SD.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, original.PixelFormat);

        // Setting the Encoder for the image.
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
        Encoder myEncoder; // Guid Encoder
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter; // Pass a value to an Image Encoder
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters; //Encapsulates an array of EncoderParameter objects

        // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(newCodec);
        // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
        // for the Quality parameter category.
        myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        // Create an EncoderParameters object.
        // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter
        // objects. In this case, there is only one
        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, qualityLevel);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

        //Set image resolution (horizontal and vertical)
        temp.SetResolution(newResolution, newResolution);

        //Get a Graphics object from the bitmap.
        SD.Graphics newImage = SD.Graphics.FromImage(temp);
        // Quality settings output image
        newImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        newImage.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        newImage.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        newImage.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        //Draw the image with the new width/height
        newImage.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        //Save the bitmap with appropirate Codec
        temp.Save(outputFileName, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

        //Dispose of our objects.
        original.Dispose();
        temp.Dispose();
        newImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Which line gives the error? As GIF images use indexes to specify the colour of each pixel rather than explicit RGB values you will need to use a different method to read it in.

Comment: SD.Graphics newImage = SD.Graphics.FromImage(temp);

Comment: Line above create the error. Can you give me an example of different method? Can I have also the same problem with PNG Files?

Comment: I've taken a quick look - but it should work. I was expecting the line `SD.Bitmap temp = new SD.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, original.PixelFormat);` to be failing as you are using the image pixel format which will be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
SD.Bitmap temp = new SD.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, original.PixelFormat);
```

into

```
SD.Bitmap temp = new SD.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the problem:

```
   SD.Bitmap temp = new SD.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, original.PixelFormat);
```

You are using the pixel format of the image you have just read in - in this case GIF, so this is what is failing.

You need to use a non-index pixel format for this.